# Split BulkColumn into Rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have the following Data currently stored in a CSV file:

```
253056.0015
253056.0016
253056.0010
253056.0011
253056.0012
253056.0013
253056.0014
253056.0007
253056.0008
253056.0009
253056.0006
253056.0005
252914.0028
253056.0001
253056.0002
253056.0003
253056.0004
253058.0001
252914.0026
252914.0027
252914.0023
252914.0024
252914.0025
252914.0015
252914.0016
```

All the above data is in one column.

When I run the following query:

```
select
    *
from 
    openrowset(bulk 'C:\Audits.csv', single_clob) as data;
```

I get the data like this:

[image: Results1]

How do I get the data to show it exactly as it looks in the CSV file?

i.e - showing it underneath each other in rows like this:

[image: Expected Results]

I've tried the following, but did not succeed...

```
declare @results varchar(max)

select
@results = BulkColumn
from openrowset(bulk 'C:\Audits.csv',single_clob) as data;

select value from string_split(@results, ' ');
```

Please help.

Comment: Which version you have? What did you mean by `"but did not succeed"`?

Comment: I did not succeed, because it still shows the data exactly the same as the first query...

Comment: [Oops](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=45d680f0f6e8414066a2ab17add4caab) so what you think a white space isn't really a white space.

Comment: remember the source data is in CSV format, for some reason, the `string_split`, still does not split it...

Comment: Did you try with `(SELECT SUBSTRING(@results , 12, 1))` instead of `' '`?

Comment: Perfect! That worked. Please answer this question with the above answer...

Comment: @Birel you don't need `STRING_SPLIT` in the first place. `BULK` allows you to specify a format file where you can specify your own field delimiter

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos, I tried what you suggested and didn't succeed - kept getting an error, but I'm sure the answer GarethD provided would work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you thin it's a white space `' '` isn't really a white space.

You can use `(SELECT SUBSTRING(@results , 12, 1))` as

```
select value from string_split(@results, (SELECT SUBSTRING(@results , 12, 1)));
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the columns directly from `OPENROWSET` you need to define a [Format File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/create-a-format-file-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). A simpler alternative would be to use [`BULK INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), e.g.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#Data', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Data;

CREATE TABLE #Data (Value DECIMAL(10, 4));

BULK INSERT #Data 
FROM 'C:\Audits.csv'
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW = 1,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);

SELECT *
FROM #Data;
```

N.B This would work with just:

```
CREATE TABLE #Data (Value DECIMAL(10, 4));
BULK INSERT #Data 
FROM 'C:\Audits.csv';
```

But I included the options as these are fairly common things that may need to be amended.

Comment: Thanks @GarethD, wil be sure to use this going forward